# rendering form, and display the input on the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

so I'm trying to create a videogame review website for practice. each game would have it's own page, and on each page, i'd like to have a form where you can input reviews, and have it show up on the same page when submitted.

I'm not sure how to handle this. but I managed to create two controllers -- one for creating games, and one for creating reviews.

I use devise for user logins/registration

I'll post the codes below: please let me know if you need to see other files.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  resources :games
  resources :reviews

  root "games#index"

end
```

**games_controller.rb** -- to create new games

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController

    before_action :set_game, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @games = Game.all
    end

    def new
        @game = Game.new
    end

    def create
        @game = Game.create(game_params)
        redirect_to @game
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        @game.update(game_params)
        redirect_to @game
    end

    def destroy
    end

    private

    def game_params
        params.require(:game).permit(:title, :image, :developer, :genre, :release_date, :platform)
    end

    def set_game
        @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

**reviews_controller.rb** -- to create reviews

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :set_review, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @review = Review.new
    end

    def create
        @review = Review.create(review_params)
        redirect_to @review
    end

    private

    def review_params
        params.require(:review).permit(:review)
    end

    def set_review
        @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

**show.html.erb** for games

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <p class=""><%= link_to "Update Details", edit_game_path %></p>
    <p class=""><%= link_to "Update News", new_game_path %></p>
<% end %>

<%= flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated." %>
<hr>
<div class="game_summary">
    <%= image_tag @game.image %>
    <div class="game_details">
        <h3 class="game_title"><%= @game.title %></h3>
        <ul class="game_info">
            <li>Developer: <%= @game.developer %></li>
            <li>Release Date: <%= @game.release_date %></li>
            <li>Genre: <%= @game.genre %></li>
            <li>Platform(s): <%= @game.platform %></li>
        </ul>
        <button class="buttons" id="buy">Buy</button>
        <button class="buttons" id="rent">Rent</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="game_news">
    <h2 class="game_news_title">News & Articles</h2>
</div>

<div class="game_reviews">
    <%= link_to "Add Review", new_review_path %>    
    <h2>Reviews</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><%= %></li>
        <li><%= %></li>
        <li><%= %></li>
        <li><%= %></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: Also - have you read through the Rails Guides here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

In your `games_controller.rb`, you'd need a `show` method (which is created by default when you use scaffolding, but which you somehow missed). This `show` method would gather all the reviews pertaining to the game in question, assuming your `Review` model has a reference to its corresponding `Game` model (both as a foreign key specified in `schema.rb` and via `belongs_to` and `has_many` in their respective models).

The show method would look like this:

```
def show
  @reviews = Review.where("game_id = ?", @game.id)
end
```

Then in your view, you'd have something like this:

```
<% @reviews.each do | review | %>
  <%= review.title %>
  <%= review.content %>
<% end %>
```

I have no idea what fields are contained in your Review object, but you can extrapolate from this example to get what you want.